# How can an activity with 'singleTask' launch mode be not root activity in a task?

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

This is an image from android documentation:

[image]

Activity Y has 'singleTask' launch mode but it is not root activity in the task, that is Activity X. How did it happen?

Upd.:

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> "singleTask"
>
> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.
> Note: Although the activity starts in a new task, the Back button still returns the user to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is that this activity was launched with an intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag, because intents have higher priority than xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

Single task only means that this activity can only be created once cf to this website: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

It doesn't matter if the activity is root or not.

> singleTask:
>
> This mode is quite different from standard and singleTop. An Activity
>   with singleTask launchMode is allowed to have only one instance in the
>   system (a.k.a. Singleton). If there is an existed Activity instance in
>   the system, the whole Task hold the instance would be moved to top
>   while Intent would be delivered through onNewIntent() method.
>   Otherwise, new Activity would be created and placed in the proper
>   Task.

Comment: Hm, it does not agree with the official documentation... I've just posted an update to the question.

Comment: Though on second look it seems the same, the only way to start an activity is to create a new task where it will be in the root.